# How does TOR keep its relays secret and stay unblocked and usable?

Tags: networking, proxy, tor

How does TOR (The Onion Router) maintain a list of servers, that are publicly available to everyone, unblocked?

Answer (score 3):

They don't. Tor does nothing to keep relays and exits from getting blocked. Read over this Exit Router template that they provide, particularly the last couple of paragraphs.

https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git?a=blob_plain;hb=HEAD;f=contrib/tor-exit-notice.html

Anyone can take the list of nodes from https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py and block all of the IP addresses. I can also block all of the IP addresses allocated to China or Russia but do the losses justify the gains?

They do have entry points to the network called bridges that is secret in order for more people be able to use Tor.

Answer (score 1):

They kind of cover it in their about section. https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en

Comment: Where exactly? I haven't read anything on the topic of how they keep relays from being blocked!

Comment: You can block individual relays, but then another circuit gets built that would bypass it. Unless that relay is blocked. They depend on more and more users in the system to create circuits through until it's not feasible to block them.